# Google maps (integrated by API) - coordinates wrong

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to embed google maps by API to my page and I'm using following code:

```
function initialize() {
  var address = '50.0911676,14.429257099999973';      
  var ad = address.split(',');;
  var myLatLng = {lat: parseInt(ad[0]), lng: parseInt(ad[1])};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Here is the element HTML, where the map is loaded:

```
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Everything seems forking, but the address which is loaded is wrongly placed. The address should be following: `Soukenická 1196/11, 110 00` Praha 1 and if you put to google the coordinates `50.0911676,14.429257099999973` you'll get it as well, but on the loaded map it's wrong.

Could anybody help me to find what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Int" in `parseInt()` means **integer**. The fractional parts of your coordinates are being lost.

Instead of

```
var address = '50.0911676,14.429257099999973';      
var ad = address.split(',');;
```

just use numbers:

```
var ad = [50.0911676, 14.429257099999973];
```

No need for `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks, in fact, it needs to set it as `parseFloat()` because if not, it fails with not a `LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number` but you have opened my eyes! thanks a lot!

Comment: A number that's coded as a number (and not a quoted string) does not need to be passed through `parseFloat()`. If you do that, what JavaScript does is convert the number *to a string* first, then parse it as a number, and return the result. A numeric constant like `50.0911676` does not need to be parsed; the JavaScript parser parses it when it interprets the constant.

Comment: But I'm loading that number form php form a string field and somehow it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Well yes, sure; if you really do start off with a string, then you use `parseFloat()` to convert :)